# Close all existing windows in pygobject

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I am using pygobject in python. (see my system specs. at end)

I have a multiple window app.

I want to close all windows and quit the main loop, but continue execution of code

If I call `Gtk.main_quit` all the windows keep in the screen and of course don't respond.

Example code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
    
win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect('button-press-event', Gtk.main_quit)
win.show()
Gtk.main()

input('press Enter to end:')
```

I have connected the mouse click event to `main_quit` so when I click the window, the main_quit es fired, exiting the main gtk loop and then the last line is reached. But the window does not get destroyed. Only when I press Enter and the program exits the window is   destroyed

So I suppose I have to destroy all windows one by one.

Is there some way of closing all windows at once?

And a related question: Is it ok to exit the python app without destroying all windows first?

**My system is:**

PyGObject 3.38

python 3.9.5

linux: Pop!_OS 21.04

Gnome Version 3.38.5

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? `Gtk.main_quit()` should work, but I can't see what you're doing in the actual code, so I can't tell what the error might be. And no, I think it's better to destroy all the windows first (which `Gtk.main_quit()` already does), than to simply exit the program, because some background processes may continue to run after the program's execution has stopped. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Ok, I just added it. I think main_quit does not is supposed to destroy windows though.

Comment: I found out the `Gtk.Window.list_toplevels` function. So I can use that to close all windows.

Comment: Oops! You're right; `Gtk.main_quit()` does not destroy the windows. My mistake! I guess I thought it did because my programs all ended right after calling `main_quit()`, so the windows get deleted when the programs stop.